# how to use decorator pattern to directly modify members of base class?

Tags: c++, decorator

Base class A:

```
class A {
public:
    A() {}
    ~A() {}
    void methodOfA() { fill(array_.begin(), array_.end(), 100); }
private: 
    vector<int> array_;
};
```

Decorator class B:

```
class B: public A {
    A* a_;
public: 
    B(A* a) { a_ = a; }
    ~B() {}
    A* getA() { return a_; }
};
```

Now if I create an instance of B and use it like the following:

```
A a;
B b(&a);
b.methodOfA();
```

I want b to access or change everything that a has. To do that, one can use:

```
b.getA()->methodOfA();
```

This does not look good to me, is there any way to do something like:

```
b.methodOfA();
```

but achieve the same effect as b.getA()->methodOfA(); Note that A may not have a copy constructor to copy everything to B and I want everything done to b that happen in a.

**To clarify:**
If I override every member functions of A (e.g. methodOfA()) in B, I can achieve what I want above. But there are about 50 functions in A to override. Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two solutions:

**1 - Private inheritance**

```
struct A {
    void stuff() {}
};

struct B : private A {
    using A::stuff;
};

int main() {
    B b;
    b.stuff(); // OK
}
```

You'll need to list all of `A`'s methods, but you don't have to redefine anything.

**2 - Operator overloading**

```
struct A {
    void stuff() {}
};

struct B {

    A *operator -> () {
        return &a;
    }

    A a;
};

int main() {
    B b;
    b->stuff(); // Yuck. But OK.
}
```

On one hand, you can't have the `b.stuff()` syntax without implementing the `stuff` method in either `B` or one of its bases. On the other hand, overloading an operator may not be intuitive to user code. I guess you'll have to choose your poison.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `A::methodOfA()` needs to be virtual.

Then, in B, you need to add this:

```
virtual void methodOfA() { a_->methodOfA(); }
```

That's the decorator pattern.

Theoretically there could be a utility which, given a class, automatically generates a decorator for it, but I am not aware of any.

There is a number of things you can do to reduce the number of methods of `A` so as to make writing your decorator easier:

1. Combine multiple methods which do not really need to be different into one.  For example, `raiseFlag()` and `lowerFlag()` can become `setFlag( bool flag )`.
2. Extract the public interface of `A` into a separate class `I`, and make both `A` and `B` extend `I`. Then, remove utility methods of `A` (methods implemented by invoking other methods of the same interface) put them in `I`, and make them non-virtual. So, you will have a reference to an `I` which implements some methods by itself, (invoking other methods on itself,) and this `I` will be implemented by an instance of `B` in which each virtual method delegates to (decorates) the corresponding virtual method of an instance of `A`.

Also, please note that the problem with implementing the decorator pattern by writing one decorator method for each method in the original interface is just a fact of life and irrelevant to elegance.  In engineering, elegance is about avoiding hacks, not about saving keystrokes.

Comment: I think I have to clarify a bit: there are so many methods (about 50) in A. If I do something like you suggested, I will have to wrap all those methods. Is there any more elegant solution? thanks.

Comment: @newbie I amended my answer.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions. I accept that "In engineering, elegance is about avoiding hacks, not about saving keystrokes." But in this particular case, elegance not just saves keystrokes but also avoids hacks. Imagine that if A's author adds a new method and the decorator class B forget to override it, that may cause problem:
A a;
B b(&a);
b.newMethodOfA(); // 
if newMethodOfA() modifies a member variable, it only modify members of b, not a!

Comment: Normally when you start using interfaces and delegation you stop writing code that directly references concrete classes. So, you would never directly invoke a method on an instance of `A`, only an instance of `I`.  If a method is added only to `A`, it is invisible to all the code that invokes `I`, so you immediately know you also need to add it to `I`, or else you cannot use it.

Comment: Once a pure virtual method is added to `I`, any classes that extend `I` without providing an implementation for that method are flagged by the compiler as un-instantiatable, so immediately you know in which classes you have to add implementations. So, it is safe.

Comment: Thanks, @Mike Nakis. I appreciate all your inputs here and your above comments are valid points. That's why I up-voted your answer. But personally, I don't think it's worth the efforts to create a layer of interface and delegate all the methods in both B and I - it seems like a overkill to my problem. 50+ function calls duplicated in different classes, just doesn't sound nice to read and maintain...

Comment: Thank you, and sure, it is your call.